# Spring JPA: change doesn't persist in OneToOne relationship

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I use Spring Boot Starter Data JPA for my thesis, and I have a bug, I can't quite work out.

I have the following relationship between my entitites:

**Restaurant**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurants")
public class Restaurant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    // ...

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = RestaurantTable.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_table_fk", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Set<RestaurantTable> restaurantTables;
    // ...
}
```

**RestaurantTable**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurant_table")
public class RestaurantTable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id

    // ...

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_table_id")
    private EndUser user;

    // ....

}
```

**EndUser**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "end_users")
public class EndUser {
    public EndUser(String userId, String encryptedPassword) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String userId;
    private String encryptedPassword;
}
```

Basically: Every restaurant can have many tables, and each and every table has a corresponding user.

When I create a new table I automatically create a new user for it.

**RestaurantTableService**

```
// ...

@Override
public void add(RestaurantTable restaurantTable) {
    var restaurant = getRestaurant();

    restaurantTable.setUser(
            new EndUser(idGenerationService.get(), passwordEncoder.encode(passwordGenerationService.get()))
    );

    restaurant.addTable(restaurantTable);
    restaurantRepository.save(restaurant);
}

// ...
```

This works so far. The problem is when I try to change the password of the user of a table. I tried more approaches.

**create a new user with updated password and assign it to a table**

```
var newPassword = passwordGenerationService.get();
var user = restaurantTable.getUser();
var newUser = new EndUser(user.getUserId(), passwordEncoder.encode(newPassword));

restaurantTable.setUser(newUser);
restaurantTableService.update(restaurantTable);
```

**update the existing user**

```
var newPassword = passwordGenerationService.get();
var user = restaurantTable.getUser();

user.setEncryptedPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(newPassword));

restaurantTable.setUser(user);
restaurantTableEntityService.update(restaurantTable);
```

`restaurantTableEntityService.update(restaurantTable)` looks like this:

**RestaurantTableService**

```
@Override
public void update(RestaurantTable restaurantTable) {
    var restaurant = getRestaurant();
    restaurant.updateTable(restaurantTable);
    restaurantRepository.save(restaurant);
}
```

None seems to work. The change doesn't persist. What should I change to make the password change persist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the direct repository to persist the changes you want directly

```
var newPassword = passwordGenerationService.get();
var user = restaurantTable.getUser();
user.setEncryptedPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(newPassword));
endUserRepository.save(user);
```

Comment: Thank you, very much, this worked! I don't know why I haven't tried this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to persist the change into the user entity like so:   `endUserRepository.save(user);`